# Unresolved function or method save()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

mongoose model.save() method is not being defined.

models/genre.js

```
'use strict';
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const GenreSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true}
});

GenreSchema
    .virtual('url')
    .get(function () {
        return '/catalog/genre/' + this._id;
    });

module.exports = mongoose.model('Genre', GenreSchema);
```

controllers/genreController.js

```
'use strict';
var Genre = require('../models/genre');

module.exports = {

    genre_get: function (req, res) {
        res.render('catalog/createGenre');
    },
    genre_post: function (req, res) {
        var genre = new Genre(
            { name: req.body.name }
        );
        genre.save(function (err) {
            if (err) { return err; }
            res.redirect('catalog/genre/list');
        });
    }
};
```

**Error**

[image: image of error]

I tried following some work around in jetbrains:

following them they say in the controller :

```
var Genre = require('../models/genre.js').Genre;
```

this resolved the issue and resolved function but later there was an error saying `Genre is not a constructor` while making a post request in:

```
`var genre = new Genre(
        { name: req.body.name }
    );`
```

Solved : Doing simply this resolved the problem

`var genre = mongoose.model('Genre', GenreSchema);`
`module.exports = genre;`

Comment: Also to mention a nice clean way of saving a mongoose object is, `const X = await Model.create({...});`

Answer (score 0):

You should use this way ,

```
var Genre = require('../models/genre');

module.exports = {

    genre_get: function (req, res) {
        res.render('catalog/createGenre');
    },
    genre_post: function (req, res) {
        var genre = new Genre(
            { name: req.body.name }
        );
        genre.save((err , saved)=>{ \\updated
            if (err) { return err; }
            else{
               res.redirect('catalog/genre/list');
            } 
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: It is giving me an error `genre.save(...).exec is not a function` also it is defining `undresolved save() method`

Comment: Still the same `Unresolved function or method save()`

Answer (score 0):

```
"use strict";
var Genre = require("../models/genre");

module.exports = {
  genre_get: function(req, res) {
    res.render("catalog/createGenre");
  },
  genre_post: function(req, res) {
    var genre = new Genre({ name: req.body.name });
    genre
      .save()
      .then(() => {
        res.redirect("catalog/genre/list");
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.redirect("catalog/genre/list");
      });
  }
};
```